# Input box fill up available space?

Tags: html, css

I want to set the width of the *fieldset* of this field and then have the wrapper and input box be fluid to take up the available space.

This is how far I have got with a bit of help on here:

```css
.lft { float: left; }
ul, li { list-style-type: none; vertical-align:middle; }
.ts3 { font-size: 15px; }
.dc3 { background-color: #808080; }
.tc5 { color: #333333; }
.p4 { padding: 4px; }
.r2 { border-radius: 2px; -moz-border-radius: 2px; -webkit-border-radius: 2px; }
.r6 { border-radius: 6px; -moz-border-radius: 6px; -webkit-border-radius: 6px; }
.field { line-height:27px; font-family:arial, sans-serif; border-color: #d9d9d9; border-top:solid 1px #c0c0c0; }
input.field{width:100%}
.fieldwrapper{display:inline-block; width:100%}
label{width:300px; display:inline-block; }
```

```html
<ul>
    <li>
<div class="r6 dc3 ts2 p4">
<label field_id="None" for="sender">Sender email address</label>
<div class="fieldwrapper">
<input class="field" placeholder="Email" type="text" value="">
</div>
</div>
</li></ul>
```

When I set the wrapper to 100% it stretches the whole way across, rather than the whole way across minus the width of the *fieldset*.

This is what I am trying to achieve for a fluid width site:
[image: fieldset]

Input box fill up available space?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
input.field{width:100%}
.fieldwrapper{display:inline-block; width:70%}
label{width:25%; display:inline-block; }​
```

You can adjust the width of label and input accordingly.

Demo http://jsfiddle.net/cskQ8/38/

---

New update

```
input.field{width:100%}
.fieldwrapper{ padding: 0 5px 0 0;
    overflow: hidden;}
label{width:200px; display:inline-block; float:left}​
```

Check the updated demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cskQ8/49/)

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Is there a way to fix this? I want to set a fixed width on the label and 100% on the field, but when I do it it hops down a line like this:
http://jsfiddle.net/cskQ8/40/

Comment: Do what I said below. That allows for a fixed width on the label which is obviously what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 1):

Yup, of course it does you've floated the button right taking it out of the document flow. You'll have to set right padding on the container for the input (not the fieldwrapper) to make up for the elements to the right of it.

```
 .containingDiv{padding-right:75px;}
 .fieldwrapper{width:100%;}
```

Comment: I dont understand about the containingdiv. Am I meant to be adding an additional div?

Answer (score 0):

If you structure your CSS and markup in a more semantic manner now, future you will be very grateful. Definition lists are an appropriate place to start:

```
<dl class="form-container clearfix">
  <dt><label for="sender">Sender email address</label></dt>
  <dd><input placeholder="Email" type="text" value="" /></dd>
</dl>
```

And CSS (remember to include a clearfix):

```
.form-container { /*just whatever styles you had applied*/}

/*label container, fixed width*/
.form-container>dt {float:left; width:150px;}

/*input container, defaults to width:auto*/
.form-container>dd { margin-left:150px; }

/*box-sizing property is the best thing since sliced bread*/
.form-container input[type=text] {width:100%;box-sizing:border-box;padding:4px;}
```

​
[Fiddled](http://jsfiddle.net/ovfiddle/cskQ8/53/), try resizing the *result* frame and see how fluid it is!

Comment: Thank you! How would this work with complicated fields, like for example a WYSIWYG field and a image upload field?

Comment: You'll basically need to correctly clear the float on `<dt>` elements - try looking up some form layout tutorials that advocate definition lists as well